# handle of cropper(upper left) in React-image-crop is not working correctly in terms of selected aspect ratio during resizing. What can be the issue?

Tags: css

I implemented react-image0crop in a project but after testing with different size of images(landscape & portrait)I spotted an issue with cropper frame handler -
[3 handlers are working fine marked as green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psodf.png)

Problem with red is I am using aspect ratio as `aspect : 16/9` so when after I select an image from my computer then cropper frame is appearing with correct aspect ratio but when I drag cropper to bottom and then start resizing cropper frame using **top left  using crop frame's handler (marked as red in previous screenshot)** it is resizing but aspect ration is not maintaining during this resizing process
code sand box link is here - https://codesandbox.io/s/72py4jlll6

here is complete code -
`

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import ReactCrop from 'react-image-crop';
import 'react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.css';

import './App.css';

class App extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    src: null,
    crop: {
      unit: '%',
      width: 30,
      aspect: 16 / 9
    }
  };

  onSelectFile = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener('load', () =>
        this.setState({ src: reader.result })
      );
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  // If you setState the crop in here you should return false.
  onImageLoaded = (image) => {
    this.imageRef = image;
  };

  onCropComplete = (crop) => {
    this.makeClientCrop(crop);
  };

  onCropChange = (crop, percentCrop) => {
    // You could also use percentCrop:
    // this.setState({ crop: percentCrop });
    this.setState({ crop });
  };

  async makeClientCrop(crop) {
    if (this.imageRef && crop.width && crop.height) {
      const croppedImageUrl = await this.getCroppedImg(
        this.imageRef,
        crop,
        'newFile.jpeg'
      );
      this.setState({ croppedImageUrl });
    }
  }

  getCroppedImg(image, crop, fileName) {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
    const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
    const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = crop.width * pixelRatio * scaleX;
canvas.height = crop.height * pixelRatio * scaleY;

ctx.setTransform(pixelRatio, 0, 0, pixelRatio, 0, 0);
ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high';

ctx.drawImage(
  image,
  crop.x * scaleX,
  crop.y * scaleY,
  crop.width * scaleX,
  crop.height * scaleY,
  0,
  0,
  crop.width * scaleX,
  crop.height * scaleY
);

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  canvas.toBlob(
    (blob) => {
      if (!blob) {
        //reject(new Error('Canvas is empty'));
        console.error('Canvas is empty');
        return;
      }
      blob.name = fileName;
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.fileUrl);
      this.fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      resolve(this.fileUrl);
    },
    'image/jpeg',
    1
  );
});
```

}

render() {
const { crop, croppedImageUrl, src } = this.state;

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div>
      <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={this.onSelectFile} />
    </div>
    {src && (
      <ReactCrop
        src={src}
        crop={crop}
        ruleOfThirds
        onImageLoaded={this.onImageLoaded}
        onComplete={this.onCropComplete}
        onChange={this.onCropChange}
      />
    )}
    {croppedImageUrl && (
      <img alt="Crop" style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }} src={croppedImageUrl} />
    )}
  </div>
);
```

}
}

ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('root'));
`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.